# Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument from BsonType 'Array'

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

Attempting to run the following code:

```
var doc = BsonDocument.Parse(rawjson);
```

where rawjson is:

```
[{"PersonName":"Jim Test"}]
```

Returns the following error:

```
Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument' from BsonType 'Array'.
```

The rawjson appears to be valid according to most online json validators. Is there some other way that this is to be parsed into a BsonDocument with the Mongodb C# driver?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't clarify exactly the data type of `rawjson`, I'd assumed you meant string.

The manual for [BsonDocument.Parse()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument_Parse.htm) method specifies that it accepts `string` as a parameter.

Either, your "raw json" could be a string of a JSON document:

```
var rawjson = "{'PersonName': 'Jim Test'}";
Console.WriteLine(BsonDocument.Parse(rawjson));
```

Or, it could be an array of JSON document in string format:

```
string[] rawjson = { "{'PersonName': 'Jim Test'}" };
Console.WriteLine(BsonDocument.Parse(rawjson[0]));
```

Or, if your raw json string actually is in the form of string of array document:

```
var rawjson = "[{'PersonName': 'Jim Test'}]";

string[] separatingChars = { "[", ",", "]" };  // split on these chars
string[] docs = rawjson.Split(separatingChars, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );  

foreach (string doc in docs) {
    Console.WriteLine(BsonDocument.Parse(doc));
}
```

Comment: I mentioned in the post that the raw json is: [{"PersonName":"Jim Test"}]
Hoping for a solution that does not involve doing character replacements as that can get messy in the future potentially. thank you though. It seems as though you can serialize it to List<BsonDocument> so maybe there is a way to merge a List<BsonDocument> to a single BsonDocument?

Comment: @PaulW. Sorry to clarify, what I meant was the data type of `{"PersonName":"Jim Test"}`. is it a custom object, or [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), or [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) ?  One way to merge an array of BsonDocument to a single BsonDocument is to nest it. i.e. `{ foo: [ {PersonName:"A"}, {PersonName: "B"} ] }`. Would you mind sharing how do you get the value, and what you're trying to do ? Cheers.

Comment: The object is List<ExpandoObject> but we could also use Dictionary or even something like mongo BsonDocument if needed. It is raw json that we do not know about ahead of time and therefore cannot have a set C# class object like you normally would. The nesting that you describe is roughly what we are looking for.